# How to fix 'Python sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table' issue

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I through my collegue recieved `.db` file (which includes text and number data) which I need to pass into pandas dataframe for further processing. I never worked or know about SQLite. But, with few google search,I written following line of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')     # This create `data.sqlite`

sql="""
SELECT * FROM data;

"""
df=pd.read_sql_query(sql,conn)
df.head()
```

This giving me following error

```
'error Execution failed on sql ' SELECT * FROM data; 
': no such table: data
```

What table this code is referring to ? I had only `data.db`.

I do not quite understand where i am going wrong with this. Any advice how to get my data into dataframe `df`?

Comment: `data.db` is the name of the database. You create table(s) in the database, insert rows in the table(s) and write queries to get the rows of the table(s). You need a tutorial about the basics of SQL.

Comment: Any link for this ? are u talking about microsoft access tool to create table in database ?

Comment: Start here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/create-tables/ and then https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/insert/

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to SQL but based on what you've provided, "data" is referring to a table in your database "data.db".

The query that you typed is instructing the program to select all items from the table called "data". This website helped me with creating tables: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_create_table.htm